# PunBB Checking if it is front page

Tags: php, forum, punbb

Is there any is_front() function on PunBB? I have some front page specific items. How can I put them? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution here, http://punbb.informer.com/forums/topic/24871/checking-if-it-is-front-page/
The way is

```
if (FORUM_PAGE ==  'index')
```

Answer (score 1):

The homepage is `index.php` which is not used otherwise. Or I didn't understand what you meant by “front”.

Comment: Hi, @greut I've got a solution below